# How to call sink->imbue when using boost::log::init_from_settings?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

How to call sink->imbue for text file sink when using init_from_settings?
I checked the source code and didn't find a way to re-access those sinks.

Seems that register_sink_factory is the extension, but the default factories are all in init_from_settings.cpp, so I'm not able to use an a decorator pattern to implement it easily.

I tried was set global locale, but it breaks RotationSize param (which doesn't accept int with decimal point)

Another way is:

```
auto previousLocale = std::locale::global(boost::locale::generator()("zh_CN.UTF-8"));
logging::init_from_settings(settings);
logging::add_common_attributes();
std::locale::global(previousLocale);
```

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a sink factory that will configure the sink the way you need. You can find an example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension/settings.html#log.extension.settings.adding_support_for_user_defined_sinks).